# Fragment subscribe to Observer

Tags: android, observer-pattern, rx-java

I'm trying to implement an Observer/Subscriber with RxJava for the first time.
I get the compile error:

```
cannot resolve method subscribe(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
```

on the line indicated below. So I'm not subscribing correctly.
How do I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Fragment myFragment = mTabsPageAdapter.getItem(2);

        Observable<String> loadAndStoreDataObservable = Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                        try {           
                            <get data from RESTful service>
                            <write data to SQLite db on device>

                            subscriber.onNext("Done");
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(myFragment); // cannot resolve method subscribe(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
    }
}

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Observer<String> {

        @Override                         
        public void onNext(String s) {    
            System.out.println(s);        
        }                                 

        @Override                         
        public void onCompleted() {       
        }                                 

        @Override                         
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }
}
```

Edit: I changed the line suggested by Vladimir Mironov. This seems to be necessary but not sufficient. Implementing it I then get a compile error on the line after that:
*Incompatible types: Required rx.Observable
                     Found rx.Subscription*

It suggests casting to `(Observable<String>)` like so:

```
Observable<String> loadAndStoreDataObservable = (Observable<String>) Observable.create(...)
```

which does indeed compile error-free, but gives the runtime error:
*java.lang.ClassCastException: rx.observers.SafeSubscriber cannot be cast to rx.Observable*

Edit 2:
I think it should be: `Subscription loadAndStoreDataObservable = ...`

Comment: MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) mTabsPageAdapter.getItem(2);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See edit to original question.

Comment: the return type from `subscribe` is a subscription, not an observable.

Comment: loadAndStoreDataObservable should be a Subscription.

Comment: also, make sure to unsubscribe that subscription onDestroy

Comment: So the answer has 3 parts: 1: modify `getItem()` call 2: change type of loadAndStoreDataObservable to `Subscription` 3: Unsubscribe in `onDestroy()`. I don't know how this works ... whoever wants to post an answer, please do so and I will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one is stepping forward, so I'll aggregate the comments into an answer.

1. Cast to MyFragment:

   ```
   MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) mTabsPageAdapter.getItem(2);
   ```
2. Change loadAndStoreDataObservable to be a `Subscription`

   ```
   Subscription loadAndStoreDataObservable = ...
   ```
3. In `OnDestroy()`, unsubscribe:

   ```
   protected void onDestroy() {  
       super.onDestroy();  
       if (loadAndStoreDataObservable != null) {  
          loadAndStoreDataObservable.unsubscribe();  
       }
   }
   ```